# Least Squares in a Matrix Form

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I was reading through linear regression but I cannot get my head around with the notation.

Given a set of points $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n,y_n) \in \mathbf{R}$ the least-squares approximation is can be found solving

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)^2\right)~a + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)\right)~b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i$$
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)~a + n~b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$$

Up to here I understand the derivation and expressing this in matrix form is simple and looks like

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)^2 & \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i) \\
 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i & n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 a \\
 b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i \\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The problem I having is when $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n,y_n) \in \mathbf{R^n}$, how to get the previous representation to look like the normal equation

$$\hat \beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T y$$

where I guess $\hat \beta$ is a the vector with all the parameters of the linear regression. I don't see how to go from the sums to a pure matrix notation.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post this proof of least squares as this seems appropriate here. It's least squares from a linear algebra point of view, and adapted from Friedberg's [Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130084514). It requires some more involved linear algebra arguments, but I think it gives a good perspective on least squares. Plus, the normal equations just fall right out of this derivation.

First, we assume we have $N$ data points $(y_1, \mathbf{x}_1), ..., (y_N, \mathbf{x}_N),$ where $\mathbf{x}_i = (1, x_{i1}, ..., x_{ip}).$ Here $y_i$ and $x_{ij}$ are taken to be real numbers. Letting $\mathbf{X}$ be the matrix whose $i^\text{th}$ row is $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\bf{y}$ the vector whose $i^\text{th}$ component is $y_i$, the problem of least squares can be stated as finding $\beta$ satisfying:

$$
\underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{p + 1}}{\text{argmin}} \ ||\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta||^2.
$$

Remember from linear algebra, that $\bf{X}$ represents a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^{p + 1} \to \mathbb{R}^N$ given by $\mathbf{w} \mapsto \mathbf{X}\mathbf{w},$ so it makes sense to define $W$ to be the range of $\bf{X}.$ Now, from linear algebra we know that we can write 
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{z}
$$
for some $\mathbf{u} \in W, \mathbf{z} \in W^\perp,$ where $W^\perp$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ orthogonal to $W$, or the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $W.$ This vector $\mathbf{u}$ is what is usually called the orthogonal projection of $\bf{y}$ onto $W$, and already satisfies:

$$
||\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{u}||^2 \leq ||\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{w}||^2
$$

for all $\mathbf{w} \in W.$ Now, since $\mathbf{u} \in W$, then by definition $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{X}\hat{\beta}$ for some $\hat{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}^{p + 1}$ (since $W$ is the range of $\mathbf{X}$), and

$$
\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta} - \mathbf{y} = -\mathbf{z} \in W^\perp
$$

since $W^\perp$ is a subspace. Since $W^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of $W,$ then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{p + 1}$ (again since $W$ is the range of $\bf{X}$):

$$
0 = \left<\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta} - \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{X}\alpha\right> = \left<\mathbf{X}^*(\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta} - \mathbf{y}), \alpha\right>.
$$

Here $\mathbf{X}^*$ is called the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of $\mathbf{X},$ and since $\mathbf{X}$ only has real entries, $\mathbf{X}^* = \mathbf{X}^T.$ The last equation implies that

$$
0 = \mathbf{X}^*(\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta} - \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta} - \mathbf{y}) =  \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta} - \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}.
$$

If you assume $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is invertible, then this gives you:

$$
\hat{\beta} = \left(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}
$$

which are precisely the normal equations! You see that arguing in this manner bypasses the messy summation notation, and also generalizes least squares to the case where $\mathbf{y}_i, \mathbf{x}_i$ (it is easy to extend this to the case where you are regressing on vectors rather than just numeric values) are both vectors of arbitrary dimension (not necessarily equal dimension).

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$X=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & x_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n
\end{array}
\right]$$

and likewise for $y$.

Comment: Swap the columns if you want exactly your matrix.  It's standard to put the constant first, however.