# Least squares in matrix form

Tags: matrices, least-squares

So my question is eerily similar to the one asked (and answered) here: [Least Squares in a Matrix Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644834/least-squares-in-a-matrix-form)

It is different since it deals with a specific case of LS. I get stuck when taking the matrix inverse at some point in the process.

Given is the following regression model

$$y_i =\beta_1 +\beta_2x_i + \epsilon_i, \hspace{1cm}i=1,...,n$$

In matrix notation this is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1\\
1 & x_2\\
1 & x_3\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_1\\
\epsilon_2\\
\epsilon_3\\
\vdots\\
\epsilon_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now taking the general least squares equation $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, I want to plug in the values of the regression to transform it into a vector of $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$.

Multiplying

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1\\
1 & x_2\\
1 & x_3\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with its transpose

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & \dots & x_n
\end{bmatrix}

yields

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n & \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{x_i}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{x_i} & \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{x_i^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The next step would be to take the inverse of this matrix (and then multiply it by y). Unfortunately, I don't understand how to take the inverse of these sums.

Comment: You've computed $X^\top X$ correctly. To invert it, use the general formula $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: You multiplied by the _transpose_, not by the _inverse_.

Comment: Why invert the matrix?